# Como fazer a conversão de `data java.util.Date` para `java.sql.Date`?

Tags: java, mysql, data, conversão-de-tipo

A ideia é consultar os dados por *datas* no no banco (MySQL): tenho 2 campos `JXDatePicker` e quero o retorno dos dados entre a data inicial e a data final. No MySQL, o campo *data* está com o formato `DATE` (exemplo: `2017-10-11`) e no Java o campo *data* está como `java.util.Date`.

Tentei fazer a conversão porém ele não filtra as datas e não retorna o resultado. O que há de errado?

**Método de consulta:**

```
  public List<FinancasModel> listaPorDatas(Date dataInicio, Date dataFinal) throws ParseException {

    System.out.println("Datas " + dataInicio + " " + dataFinal);

    String sql = "select * from financas where dataPagamento between ? and ? ";

    List<FinancasModel> listaPorDatas = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = getCon().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dataInicio.getTime()));
        ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dataFinal.getTime()));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs != null) {
            while (rs.next()) {

                FinancasModel fm = new FinancasModel();
                fm.setCodFinancas(rs.getInt(1));
                fm.setValor(rs.getDouble(2));
                fm.setDataPagamento(rs.getDate(3));
                fm.setDataCadastro(rs.getDate(4));
                fm.setTipo(rs.getString(5));
                fm.setDescricao(rs.getString(6));
                fm.setObservacao(rs.getString(7));

                listaPorDatas.add(fm);
            }

        } else {

            return null;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro: " + e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

**Método de listagem da consulta:**

```
public void listaPorDatas(Date dataInicio, Date dataFinal) throws ParseException {

    FinancasDAO cd = new FinancasDAO(con);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbl_movimentacao.getModel();
    model.setNumRows(0);
    List<FinancasModel> listaPorDatas = cd.listaPorDatas(dataInicio, dataFinal);
    double despesa = 0;
    double renda = 0;
    for (FinancasModel fb : listaPorDatas) {
        if (fb.getTipo().equals("DESPESA")) {
            despesa += fb.getValor();
        } else {
            renda += fb.getValor();
        }
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            fb.getCodFinancas(),
            Utils.ConverteDouble(fb.getValor()),
            fb.getDataPagamento(),
            fb.getTipo(),
            fb.getDescricao(),
            fb.getObservacao()

        });
    }
    txt_despesa.setText(Utils.ConverteDouble(despesa));
    txt_renda.setText(Utils.ConverteDouble(renda));
    txt_saldo.setText(Utils.ConverteDouble(renda - despesa));
}
```

**Erros retornados:**

> Datas Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 BRT 2017 Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 BRT 2017
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   br.com.smartadvocacy.telas.Movimentacao.listaPorDatas(Movimentacao.java:44)
>     at
>   br.com.smartadvocacy.telas.Movimentacao.BuscarMouseClicked(Movimentacao.java:348)
>     at
>   br.com.smartadvocacy.telas.Movimentacao.access$200(Movimentacao.java:25)
>     at
>   br.com.smartadvocacy.telas.Movimentacao$4.mouseClicked(Movimentacao.java:252)
>     at
>   java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6536)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Pode informar qual a versão do Java que usa?

Comment: Java: 8, Atualização 144

Comment: Embora sua pergunta seja como converter os tipos de objetos de datas, seu problema não parece estar ligado a conversão. Você teve um `Datas Fri Sep 01 00:00:00 BRT 2017 Sun Oct 01 00:00:00 BRT 2017 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at br.com.smartadvocacy.telas.Movimentacao.listaPorDatas(Movimentacao.java:44) at `. O que não prece ter haver com tipo X ou Y de data, mas um objeto nulo. Verifique o que tem na linha 44 da classe Movimentacao.